# Return most recent results with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to find the most recent three results (front top to bottom) in a Google Sheet where column L is "Signed" and the result (column T) is not 0 or blank.

I have the below so far which gives me the first result but not filtered by column L and not excluding 0 or blank cells.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX('Print List'!T$2:T,SMALL(IF("Alex"='Print List'!A$2:A,ROW(A$2:A)-1),1))))

(edit: or rather than ignoring 0 or blanks - column F must be "Sold" so could also filter by that.)

I need to display the results for 1st, 2nd and 3rd in separate columns so will replace the 1 at the end of the above with appropriate number.

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

Hope I have explained myself ok and any help received will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this off to the side somewhere, or on a different tab, where I assume your tab name is Sheet1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Print List'!A:T,"select T where T>0 and L='Signed' limit 3"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That did work but not exactly what I need. I modified to the below but I don't think a query is going to work here.

'=QUERY('Print List'!A:T,"select A,L,T where A='Alex' and T>0 and L='Signed' limit 3")'

I need the results for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd answers to go in subsequent columns.

Not sure if I can post Dropbox links to a screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7jwq7p5lpau2cm/Screenshot%202020-10-21%20at%2018.41.04.png?dl=0

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @AlxAndrws I'll edit my answer above to try to give you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging I have got it to work! Thanks Matt for pointing me in the right direction.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY('Print List'!A:T,"select T where A='"&$A2&"' and T>0 and L='Signed'",0), 1, 1), 1),"")`

EDIT: Improved again using Matt's edited suggestion:

`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Print List'!A:T,"select T where A='"&$A2&"' and F='Sold' and L='Signed' limit 3","")),"")`

Thank you.